# Injecting advice to a recursive method in Spring.Net?

Tags: c#, recursion, aop, spring.net

I'm trying to use Spring.NET's support for AOP to do dependency injection/inversion of control/aspect-oriented programming (sorry for the slew of buzzwords - maybe I'll post a separate question asking someone to clarify the difference :)  ).

Specifically, I want to have intercept a recursive method call, so that every time that the method is invoked, the AOP advice/interceptor will be called.

Spring.Net doesn't appear to intercept anything other than the very first method call.  I *think* that Spring.Net is maintaining exactly 1 chain of interceptors per instance, and not call any more interceptors until that first method invocation has finished.

Does anybody have any info about getting the interceptor (the advice) to be triggered for EVERY method invocation, including recursive calls?

I can provide code/example output, if that's helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

See http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=5331

Answer (score 2):

If you are using proxy-based AOP then this will not work for recursive method calls. The first call against the target will be intercepted by the proxy and your advice will run. Then the method on the target will be invoked, and subsequent calls will stay within the target class, ignorant of the proxy. The only way to make this work is to actually modify your bytecode so that class itself contains the behavior.

I actually haven't worked with Spring.NET (only Spring with Java) so I'm unfortunately ignorant about what kinds of bytecode weaving options exist in the .NET universe.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't Spring.NET per se, but have a look at [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/).  It gives you compile time weaving that doesn't rely on dynamic proxies, and would handle the recursive method call.  The configuration is slightly different though...